# Busy SQL Server + Python = Lost Transactions?

Tags: python, sql-server, transactions

Started my day with a call saying users can't log in to the application because it was timing out.  Look, OK, server is busy but humming along.  Few minutes later, people are back in.

Then I get a call that a bunch of invoices created in that time were "missing".  Invoices are created by a multi step stored procedure. The proc does several inserts and updates, it *does not* use a SQL transaction. Last step, it queries the data to return it to the client.  Return data query does not use (nolock). The dev running Python has invoiceIDs returned by the proc logged.  A SQL job that queries and saves off new invoice data every minute caught this data and stored it successfully to a side table. Yes, this job uses nolock so would have included "dirty reads", but the data existed at one point. Everything else is MIA.  The inserts, and the updates all look like this was rolled back.  I have a 2 hour gap between invoices and 30 odd were created in that time, now simply gone.

YES, Python has autocommit=true

NO, SQL did not crash, it's been up since 5/23/2021.

```
DATABASE = {
    'server': getenv('DATABASE_HOST', ''),
    'database': 'PS',
    'user': getenv('DATABASE_USER', ''),
    'password': getenv('DATABASE_PASS', ''),
    "port": 1433,
    "timeout": TIMEOUT,
    "as_dict": True,
    **"autocommit": True**
}

LOGGER.info(f'calling {PROC_NAME[name]} with {dumps(args, indent=4)}')
    try:
        self.cursor.callproc(PROC_NAME[name], args)
    except PytdsError as exc:
        LOGGER.error(str(exc))
        raise ServiceError(str(exc))
    try:
        rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
        return rows
    except PytdsError as exc:
        if raise_error:
            raise ServiceError(str(exc))
        return []
```

This code has been in production for a while.  It works. I SUSPECT it's Python, keeping the trans open until the connection is closed not when the proc completes but I don't know how to prove it.  Help?

Comment: Please show the code for the procedure

Comment: Use of NOLOCK and a lack of transactions means this workflow only "works" when there is little resource contention. After the fact I don't think you can "prove" anything.